# Calculate the average score of groups and each student, C

Tags: c

I have a file containing information about the session of students. The structure of this file is: group number, student name, exams, and tests.

- `debt()` function find and print the names of underachieving students.
- `student_score()` calculate the average score of groups
- `group_score()` calculate the average score of each student.

So, this is my program and maybe I can make something better?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define N 50

void debt();
void student_score();
void group_score();

struct STUDENTS {
  int group;
  char name[100];
  char test[15];
  int exam;
};

struct STUDENTS student_list[N];

int main() {
  FILE *file;
  int choice;
  char buffer[200];
  int i = 0;

  file = fopen("students.txt", "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    puts("students.txt не найден");
    return 1;
  }

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file) != NULL) {
    sscanf(strdup(buffer), "%d %[^0-9] %d %s", &student_list[i].group, student_list[i].name, &student_list[i].exam, student_list[i].test);
    i++;
  }
  fclose(file);
  int student_list_size = i;

  do {
    puts("\nВыберите номер пункта меню:");
    puts("1 - Cтуденты, имеющие задолженности");
    puts("2 – Средний балл каждого студента");
    puts("3 – Средний балл всей группы");
    puts("4 - Выход\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        debt(student_list_size);
        break;
      case 2:
        student_score(student_list_size);
        break;
      case 3:
        group_score(student_list_size);
        break;
      case 4:
        break;
      default:
        puts("\nНужно вводить номер пункта от 1 до 4");
        break;
    }
  } while (choice != 4);

  return 0;
}

void debt(int student_list_size) {
  int counter_debt;
  wchar_t test_wchar[15];
  wchar_t * pch;

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  for (int i = 0; i < student_list_size; i++) {
    counter_debt = 0;
    mbstowcs(test_wchar, student_list[i].test, 15);

    pch = wcschr(test_wchar, L'н');
    while (pch != NULL) {
      counter_debt++;
      pch = wcschr(pch + 1, L'н');
    }

    if (counter_debt > 0) {
      printf("%d %s: %d\n", student_list[i].group, student_list[i].name, counter_debt);
    }
  }
}

void student_score(int student_list_size) {
  int exam;
  int average;
  int digit;
  int counter_digits;

  for (int i = 0; i < student_list_size; i++) {
    average = 0;
    digit = 0;
    counter_digits = 0;
    exam = student_list[i].exam;

    while (exam) {
      digit = exam % 10;
      average += digit;
      counter_digits++;
      exam = exam / 10;
    }

    printf("%d %s: %.1f\n", student_list[i].group, student_list[i].name, (double)average / counter_digits);
  }
}

void group_score(int student_list_size) {
  int exam;

  struct GROUP_SCORE {
    int group_score;
    int students_counter;
  };
  struct GROUP_SCORE group_list[5000] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < student_list_size; i++) {
    group_list[ student_list[i].group ].students_counter += 1;
    exam = student_list[i].exam;
    while (exam) {
      group_list[ student_list[i].group ].group_score += exam % 10;
      exam = exam / 10;
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < 5000; j++) {
    if (group_list[j].group_score > 0) {
      printf("%i: %.1f\n", j, (double)group_list[j].group_score / group_list[j].students_counter);
    }
  }
}
```

students.txt:

```
4272 Галкин Г. А. 5445 ззззз
4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333 знзнз
4273 Курочкин А. А. 3433 знзнн
4272 Козлов И. И. 4443 ззззн
```

Comment: What's specifically your question?

Comment: @SamDelaney what I can make better

Comment: the first thing to do would be fix the compiler raised errors and warnings.

Comment: @user3629249  I found no compiler errors with a C99 compiler.  What was one error you found?

Comment: @user3629249 I haven't error messages. I use Mac OS X 10.10.1 and GCC Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Completely prototype functions: `debt() student_score() group_score();`

   ```
   // void debt();
   void debt(int student_list_size);
   ```
2. Avoid naked magic numbers.  Use #define or a constant to self document various numbers.

   ```
   #define TEST_N (15)
   struct STUDENTS {
     ...
     char test[TEST_N];
   };

   void debt(int student_list_size) {
     // wchar_t test_wchar[15];
     wchar_t test_wchar[TEST_N];
     ...
     // mbstowcs(test_wchar, student_list[i].test, 15);
     mbstowcs(test_wchar, student_list[i].test, TEST_N);
   ```
3. Use `size_t` for array index types and the result of `sizeof`.  `int` may not be the right size to use as an index.  (Also `i` in `main()`)

   ```
    // void student_score(int student_list_size) {
    void student_score(size_t student_list_size) {
      ...        
      // for (int i = 0; i < student_list_size; i++) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < student_list_size; i++) {
   ```
4. Localize variables.  This approaches a style issue, but declaring variables close to their use has value.

   ```
   void student_score(int student_list_size) {
     // int exam;
     // int average;
     // int digit;
     // int counter_digits;

     for (int i = 0; i < student_list_size; i++) {
       int exam;
       int average;
       int digit;
       int counter_digits;
   ```
5. The `strdup()` serves no purpose.  Eliminate it.

   ```
   // sscanf(strdup(buffer), "%d ...
   sscanf(buffer, "%d ...
   ```
6. The return value of `sscanf()` should be checked and string widths limited.  Note: `student_list[i].name` will have a `' '` at the end.

   ```
   // sscanf(buffer, "%d %[^0-9] %d %s", &student_list[i].group, ...
   if (4 != sscanf(buffer, "%d %99[^0-9] %d %14s", &student_list[i].group, ...) {
      Handle_Format_Error();
   ```
7. Use valid `main()` signature.

   ```
   int main() {
   int main(void) {
   ```
8. Conversions `char` to/from `wchar_t` may need different sizes.
9. The extra `'\n'` in `puts("4 - Выход\n");` looks wrong.  Guess I am not a fan of `puts()`.  Why not use 1 function call?

   ```
   fputs("\nВыберите номер пункта меню:\n"
         "1 - Cтуденты, имеющие задолженности\n"
         "2 – Средний балл каждого студента\n"
         "3 – Средний балл всей группы\n"
         "4 - Выход\n"
         "\n", stdout);
   ```

Comment: this 'int main(void) {' is NOT a valid main declaration

Comment: placing the variables inside the 'for' loop will result in the manipulation of the stack to push/pop those variables in each iteration of the 'for' loop  This results in unnecessary code and takes CPU cycles.

Comment: @user3629249 `int main(void)` is valid.  "... It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
`int main(void)` ... or with two parameters ..." C11 5.1.2.2.1 1

Comment: @user3629249 1) C certainly does not specify the push/pop activity in your comment.  2) A good compiler would not do so anyways. 3) The dominate activity is the while loop inside.  That is where any optimizations should be had.